# Given points $A$ and $B$, what curve does the locus of points that form congruent angles take?

Tags: geometry, angle

In more mathematical terms, let $X$ be the set of points that satisfy the following condition: $\forall \, C \in X, \, m \angle ACB = k$ where $k$ is some positive real value less than $180^{\circ}$.  Depending on the angle, this set will look different.  It's well-known that for $k=90$, $X$ would be a circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$.  But for everything that's not 90, I have no idea what that curve would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ looks like an 8 or like an American football (depending on $k$).
Just find one such point $C$ and draw the circumscribed circle of $ABC$. Then the arc of that circle from $A$ to $B$ that contains $C$ is part of your $X$. 
This is so because $\angle ACB=\frac 12\angle AOB$ (where $=$ is the center of the circle).
The rest of the curve is  obtained by reflecting that arc at $AB$. (And whether or not $A,B$ themselves belong to $X$ is at least doubtful).

Comment: Oh, of course!  I kind of was hoping that the answer was something a little bit more obscure than just a circular arc (my mind was going more towards elliptic or hyperbolic style curves for some reason), but that answer actually illustrates some pretty interesting characteristics of circumscribed circles already, so I'm not complaining.